# ASP.NET 4 MVC Routes 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, umbraco

I am getting a 404 error on my page. What am I missing?

Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

In App_Start folder RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ProductDetails",
                url: "products/details",
                defaults: new { controller = "ProductDetails", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

In my ProductDetailController.cs I have:

```
public class ProductDetailsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           ProductModel Product = new ProductModel();
           //some code here
           return View("~/Views/ProductDetails/Index.cshtml", Product);
         }
    }
```

My view is located that folder structure and called Index.cshtml.

When I view the page url /products/details/ I am getting a 404 error.  What am I missing here?  Note: this is a Umbraco site.

Comment: Try using default convention for views. `return View(Product);`

Comment: Are you sure you placed your files in the right folders according to MVC conventions? I built your code and I had no problem. I suggest you to revisit your file locations.

Comment: I have ProductDetailsController.cs in the Controllers folder and my View Index.cshtml is in a sub folder called ProductDetails under the Views folder.  RouteConfig.cs is in the App_Start folder.

Comment: @user2928262 are your other views working?

Comment: All of my other views are working. This is the only custom route I am doing however. All other pages were build in umbraco and I didnt have to setup routes for them.

Comment: You need to go back and review umbraco documentation about custom routes.

Comment: Nkosi- that is a good plan. I will start looking into that.  This page is not a page within Umbraco but perhaps Umbraco routes are taking over here.

Comment: @user2928262 that is my suspicion as well. But once you check the docs you should be better informed.

Comment: Your controller needs to have a namespace defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umbraco takes over all routes so to ovveride Umbraco to create custom routes create a class called RoutingHandler in the App_Start folder with the following code:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Umbraco.Core;

    public class RoutingHandler : ApplicationEventHandler
    {
        protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            RegisterCustomRoutes();
        }

        private static void RegisterCustomRoutes()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ProductDetails",
                url: "products/details",
                defaults: new { controller = "ProductDetails", action = "Index" }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just as an example: EDIT: in this cast Multi is the name of my View Multi.cshtml

```
    public ActionResult Index(string playerId)
    {
        var model = new MultiPlayerLabelModel();

        try
        {
            var player = ServiceFactory.GetPlayerService().GetPlayer(playerId);
            model = ServiceFactory.GetLabelService().GetLabelModels(player.Position, null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            LogService.Log.Error("Failed to generate label for player");
        }

        return View("Multi", model);
    }
```